# Cannot load csv file into mysql table

Tags: mysql, load

I am trying to load a csv file into a table using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'tprot.csv' INTO TABLE tprot FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY `'\n' SET id=null;`
```

and getting the following:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
```

Here are the columns in my table:

```
mysql> show columns from tprot;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idindex   | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| correct   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| incorrect | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 1a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 2a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 3a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 4a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 5a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 6a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 7a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 8a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 9a        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 10a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 11a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 12a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 13a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 14a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 15a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 16a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 17a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 18a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 19a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 20a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 21a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 22a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 23a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 24a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 25a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 26a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 27a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 28a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 29a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 30a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 31a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 32a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 33a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 34a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 35a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 36a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 37a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 38a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 39a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 40a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 41a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 42a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 43a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 44a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 45a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 46a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 47a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 48a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 49a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 50a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 51a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 52a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 53a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 54a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 55a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 56a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 57a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 58a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 59a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 60a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 61a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 62a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 63a       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
66 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the link to the file is:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zSVFUTlNUV1dMQkU/edit?usp=sharing
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling SQL to set the column 'id' to null. There is no such column in your table.

Try this instead.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'tprot.csv' INTO TABLE tprot FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY `'\n' SET idindex=null;`
```

That said, this would probably result in null IDs for every row, instead of the imported value.

Completely un-tested, but this is my first assumption.

Edit:

Perhaps try using mysqlimport from the command line.

```
mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by=\, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n tprot tprot.csv
```

Reference: http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqlimport1.html

Comment: I think that solves my intial querey, however it's resulting in ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat - which i think is a permissions issue

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a permission issue. Ensure the MySQL process has read permissions on the file in question (either by using CHMOD 777 (YUCK!) or chown to the user the mysql process runs as (better!))

Comment: If you have access to a command line on the machine on which MySQL is running, you may be better off using mysqlimport. Updating my answer now.

Comment: hmm only seems to add in one row of data using mysqlimport. also had to change tprot to my database name (which is different name). interesting. but you have solved my original querey so have accepted your answer. thanks.

Comment: That's odd RE mysqlimport. Perhaps the lines are terminated by just a \n, not a \r\n combo.